# Spark and cassandra, range query on clustering key

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have cassandra table with following structure:

> CREATE TABLE table (
>    key int,
>    time timestamp,
>    measure float,
>    primary key (key, time)
>   );

I need to create a Spark job which will read data from previous table, **within specified start and end timestamp** do some processing, and flush results back to cassandra.

So my spark-cassandra-connector will have to do a range query on clustering cassandra table column.

Are there any performance differences if I do:

```
sc.cassandraTable(keyspace,table).
as(caseClassObject).
filter(a => a.time.before(startTime) && a.time.after(endTime).....
```

so what I am doing is loading all the data into Spark and applying filtering

OR if I do this:

```
sc.cassandraTable(keyspace, table).
where(s"time>$startTime and time<$endTime)......
```

which filters all the data in Cassandra and then loads smaller subset to Spark.

The selectivity of a range query will be around 1%
It is impossible to include partition key in the query.

Which of these two solutions is preferred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sc.cassandraTable(keyspace, table).where(s"time>$startTime and time<$endTime)
```

Will be MUCH faster. You are basically doing a percentage (if you only pull 5% of the data 5% of the total work) of the full grab in the first command to get the same data.

In the first case you are

1. Reading all of the data from Cassandra.
2. Serializing every object and then moving it to Spark.
3. Then finally filtering everything.

In the second case you are

1. Reading only the data you actually want from C*
2. Serializing only this tiny subset
3. There is no step 3

As an additional comment you can also put your case class type right in the call

```
sc.cassandraTable[CaseClassObject](keyspace, table)
```

Comment: I think 1/20th will be exaggeration. Mainly because time is clustering key, so cassandra will anyways do full table scan. But it will indeed save, time spent between moving data from cassandra to spark, which might be alot of data.

Comment: I would definitely expect it to be savings proportional to the amount of data read.

1) The number of sstables required to be read will be much less since the range scan will not require all sstables to be read while not doing the range scan would.

2) The amount of objects that have to go through the C* Jvm wil be much less, Again this is a significant amount less objects to be allocated and deserialized. So less garbage collection required and less object allocation.

3.)The amount of traffic between C* processes and Spark Executor processes is minimized. This is not a zero copy system.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. 
I expected this behaviour, but wanted to be sure. My only concern was that cassandra will have to do a full table scan (because I do not specify any conditions on partition key), but anyway, second solution is way way better..

Comment: It will do a full table scan in both cases, but the second table scan is on a big diet :)